# AvalonEdit as a text viewer - no caret

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I want AvalonEdit to be a text viewer.

I can make:

```
textEditor.IsReadOnly = true;
```

and the control does not allow to make any changes, but it still behave like an editor - shows a caret, and using navigation keys (arrows, page up/down) moves the caret instead of scrolling the view.

Is there any way to make it a viewer? Or at least, hide the caret?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AvalonEdit is made up of three components:

- `TextEditor`, which wraps a `TextArea` in a `ScrollViewer` and adds a high-level `TextBox`-like API
- `TextArea`, which takes a `TextView` and adds the caret, selection and input handling
- `TextView`, which is the actual code display

So to disable all editing functionality, you can directly use the `TextView` class. To enable scrolling, you'll need to wrap it in a `ScrollViewer` yourself (important: enable `CanContentScroll` to avoid rendering invisible portions of the document)

```
<ScrollViewer
       Focusable="False"
       CanContentScroll="True"
       VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <avalonedit:TextView Name="textView" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

By using the `TextView` component directly, you'll need to do some of the work usually done by `TextEditor` yourself:

```
textView.Document = new TextDocument(); // create document instance
textView.LineTransformers.Insert(0,
    new HighlightingColorizer(HighlightingManager.Instance.GetDefinition("C#")));
```

---

`TextView` is not sufficient if you want to keep some of the editing functionality around (e.g. selecting text and copying it to the clipboard).
In that case, you'll need to keep using `TextEditor` or `TextArea`, and disable the undesired features.

You can't really disable the caret as the selection logic depends on having a caret, but you can hide it:

```
textEditor.TextArea.Caret.CaretBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
```

Making the document read-only will disable text input and various editing commands:

```
textEditor.IsReadOnly = true;
```

You might also want to remove commands from the text area's input handlers:

```
// remove the keyboard caret navigation and selection logic,
// but keep the mouse selection logic and editing commands
textEditor.TextArea.DefaultInputHandler.NestedInputHandlers.Remove(
    textEditor.TextArea.DefaultInputHandler.CaretNavigation);
```

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer. What would then be the correct way to add line numbers? `TextView` doesn't have this property. Tried adding `avalonedit:LineNumberMargin` but I don't know how to connect it to the text view. Setting `TextView` property causes things to hang.

Comment: Just tested the textEditor approach, and after removing CaretNavigation scrolling works like in a real viewer. This is perfect and I will probably end up using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false`:

```
textEditor.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

> It does hide the caret, but a lot of thing do not work anymore, ie. scrolling with mouse wheel

If you only want to hide the caret you could set its `CaretBrush` property to `Transparent`:

```
textEditor.TextArea.Caret.CaretBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
```

Comment: It does hide the caret, but a lot of thing do not work anymore, ie. scrolling with mouse wheel.